# How to put javascript inside conditional statement in php

Tags: javascript, php

Hi i have a simple code that detects if the file exists. And i have put a alert in the conditional statement and its working. Now what i want is to substitute that alert with a javascript alert i found online. But apparently it is not working.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
    if (file_exists($path_url)) {

    echo '<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>';
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.css">';
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    //echo 'alert("test")'; comment working alert.
    echo 'sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");';
    echo '</script>';

    $uploadOk = 0;

}

?>
```

Is it possible to put javascript inside a conditional statement in php? 
Sorry for a noob question.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: you should try putting the first two parts inside `<head></head>`. that's usually where scripts and CSS belongs.

Comment: @shadowbudz please check out my answer.

Comment: @Hassan you mean "our all" answers. OP can pick whatever one they wish.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is place these 2 lines inside `<head></head>`, which is where many scripts and CSS belong.

```
echo '<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.css">';
```

This has been tested and working.

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
<title></title>

<?php

echo '<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.css">';

?>

</head>

<body>

<?php
    if (file_exists($path_url)) {

   echo '<script language="javascript">';
    //echo 'alert("test")'; comment working alert.
    echo 'sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");';
    echo '</script>';

    $uploadOk = 0;

 }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I also included a valid doctype, just in case.

You can also place it inside `<body></body>`.

- JS scripts/CSS should be inside `<head></head>`, or as stated in comments:

*"...js script files can be put in the body and often should be put before the end body tag to stop them from locking your page from loading..."*.

References:

- http://www.w3.org/
- https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @Pete agreed. It's better to have the `<title></title>` tags also including the full and proper HTML tags. Not doing so (about title tags), the W3C validator won't validate the document and will throw a warning. I've seen that happen before, as I remember this from a question being asked here on Stack some time ago, where the OP asked why their rendered HTML didn't pass.

Comment: @Pete I've made an edit to reflect your comment. Thanks for the input Pete.

Answer (score 0):

You must have proper **HTML** `<head><body>` tags on you page to make `sweetAlert` work.

Try

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if (file_exists($path_url)) {
    echo '<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>';
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.css">';
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    //echo 'alert("test");'; //comment working alert.
    echo 'sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");';
    echo '</script>';

    $uploadOk = 0;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP wants to use a custom alert script called "'sweetAlert". Re-read the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have updated my answer. Please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

try alerting like this:

```
 if (file_exists($path_url)) {

    echo '<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>';
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.css">';

    echo '<script language="javascript">';
  // echo 'alert("test")';// comment working alert.
    echo 'setTimeout(function () {sweetAlert("Oops...","Something went wrong!", "error")}, 1000);';
    echo '</script>';

}
```

Comment: may be script is not loaded properly at the time he is alerting.